# In Scala, how can I use implicit conversion to "add" methods to subclasses of a common parent?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, implicit-conversion

Let's say I have some data in "dumb" models. In this example, I'll use `Circle` and `Triangle`, which extend a `trait Shape`.

I'm looking for a way to isolate behavior that could use these shapes, but I'm not sure the best way to structure it. If I'm trying to draw these shapes onto a document, I'd want to be able to write code that looked like this:

```scala
shapes.foreach(doc.add)
```

The trick here is that `shapes` is `Seq[Shape]`, and the `add` method is something I want to add implicitly since I can't modify the shapes themselves (nor would I want to bake this specific functionality into them).

Where I'm getting stuck is, I don't know how to mix implicit conversions with the subclasses. See `QUESTION:` below in the code for more info.

```scala
// Let's assume I'm working with some shape models that are defined in some
// external library that's out of my control.
sealed trait Shape
case class Circle() extends Shape
case class Triangle() extends Shape

// Now I'm building an add that adds stuff to a Document
// and I want to locally implement methods that work on these general shapes.
case class Document()

// Using implicit conversion to add methods to a case class that's just holding data
implicit class DocumentExtensions(doc: Document) {
  // I don't want this to be called
  def add(shape: Shape): Unit = println("Add a shape")

  // I want to use shape-specific methods
  def add(shape: Circle): Unit = println("Add a circle")
  def add(shape: Triangle): Unit = println("Add a triangle")
}

val doc = Document()
val shapes = Seq(Circle(), Triangle())

// This just prints "Add a shape" for the Circle and Triangle.
// I want to it to print "Add a circle" and "Add a triangle".
shapes.foreach { shape =>
  // QUESTION:
  // Is there a way or pattern to have this call the add for the
  // subclass instead of for Shape? I want this to be fully dynamic
  // so that I don't have to list out each subclass. Even more ideally,
  // the compiler could warn me if there was a subclass that there wasn't
  // an implicit add for.
  doc.add(shape)
}

// This would work, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this more
// dynamically without listing everything out.
shapes.foreach {
  case c: Circle => doc.add(c)
  case t: Triangle => doc.add(t)
}
```

I'm sure there's a name for what I'm looking for, but I just don't know what it is or what to search for.

Comment: You could put the pattern matching in the `add(s:Shape)` method so that it does nothing but delegate to the other `add()` methods. Not sure if that gets you closer to your goal or not.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without pattern matching or am I stuck writing all the boilerplate to match each possible type? I wasn't sure if there was a way to essentially make Scala consider the subclass before doing implicit conversion (or the equivalent) so that `add` is called on the appropriate subclass.

Comment: Scala doesn't know (in general, for a `Seq[Shape]`) the subclass at compile time, when the implicit conversion is performed. So it can't make the conversion dependent upon that. I think @jwvh has it right. You are not writing any more boilerplate, quantitatively, writing a single pattern-matched `add(...)` method than you do writing multiple per-subtype methods. (You might prefer having per subtype methods stylistically, and so have both, which would be a bit longer.)

Comment: why can't you put an abstract method in shap and then override in other case classes that way you will be able to decide which add needs to be called on runtime

Comment: @Raman while that would work too, my question mentions that I want to isolate the behavior and assume that we cannot modify the Shape classes. However, the accepted answer also offers a way to add a method to the Shape while still allowing behavior to be isolated and that was very helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: compiler cannot choose and use an implicit value specific to handle a subclass. It's basically impossible to decide what method to call (for `Triangle` or `Circle`) when you only know that it's a `Shape`. This is actually a classical problem, which has standard solutions.

**Solution 1**

Pattern matching inside `DocumentExtension.add`

Pros:

1. Since your `trait Shape` is defined as `sealed`, compiler will you if you miss a case for a certain ancestor.
2. Separation of class definition and action handling

Cons:

1. Boilerplate required to list all subclasses of your trait

**Solution 2**

Classical Visitor pattern

```
sealed trait Shape {
  def addToDoc(doc: Document, visitor: ShapeDrawer)
}
final class Triangle extends Shape {
  def addToDoc(doc: Document, visitor: ShapeDrawer) = visitor.draw(doc, this)
}
final class Circle extends Shape {
  def addToDoc(doc: Document, visitor: ShapeDrawer) = visitor.draw(doc, this)
}

trait ShapeDrawer {
  def draw(doc: Document, t: Circle)
  def draw(doc: Document, t: Triangle)
}

val drawer: ShapeDrawer = ???
val doc: Document = ???
val shapes = Seq.empty[Shape]

shapes.foreach(_.addToDoc(doc, drawer))
```

This solution also matches the requirement of being sure at compile time that you've handled every subclass of Shape, but requires adding strange methods to the trait itself.